# Как можно сделать красивее код JS

Tags: node.js, jquery, javascript

Как видно ниже, в коде много повторяющихся конструкций - отличие лишь в переменной. Как этот код можно переписать более профессионально и красивее?

```
if (type == 'private') {

    if (increment == 'plus') { privateCount++;} else if(increment == 'minus') { privateCount--;}
         io.sockets.emit('counter_'+usersOnline[socket.id], JSON.stringify({ 'privateCount' : privateCount }));

      } else if (type == 'public') {

        if (increment == 'plus') { publicCount++;} else if(increment == 'minus') { publicCount--;}
        io.sockets.emit('counter_'+usersOnline[socket.id], JSON.stringify({ 'publicCount' : publicCount }));

    } else if (type == 'chat'){

        if (increment == 'plus') { chatCount++;} else if(increment == 'minus') { publicCount--;}
        io.sockets.emit('counter_'+usersOnline[socket.id], JSON.stringify({ 'chatCount' : chatCount }));
    }
 }
```

Comment: @IOleg, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 5):

Вроде ничего не забыл...

```
 (function(type) { //чтобы не задеть message или counters если они вдруг есть в родительском scope;
 var counters = {
    'private': parseInt(privateCount)||0,
    'public': parseInt(publicCount)||0,
    'chat': parseInt(chatCount)||0
};
if (counters[type] !== undefined) {
    counters[type] += increment == 'plus' ? 1 : -1;
    var message = {};
    message[type + 'Count'] = counters[type];

    io.sockets.emit(
        'counter_' + usersOnline[socket.id],
        JSON.stringify(message));
    //тут можно вместо JSON.stringify, самому строку собрать, типа так
    //'{"'+type+'Count": '+counters[type] +'}';
    //обычно это делать нехорошо, но тут типы всех данных известны

    privateCount = counters.private;
    publicCount = counters.public;
    chatCount = counters.chat;
}
})(type);
```

Comment: не придраться :), хотя если в increment будет мусор, count сминусуется.

Comment: я знаю, думал написать это в комменте или нет..

Answer (score 2):

Не использовать, но зато 2 строчки:

```
eval(type + "Count += (increment == 'plus') ? 1 : -1;");
console.log('counter_', '{"'+type+'Count":"'+eval(type + "Count")+'"}');
```

Answer (score 0):

C вольными модификациями

```
var counters = {'private':0, 'public':0, 'chat':0 };
if (['private', 'public', 'chat'].indexOf(type) === -1) {
    return false;
}
if (increment) { // пушо нет никакого смысла в переменную "прибавление" писать не булев, а строку "минус"
    counters[type]++; // так как я тупой и не знаю, можно ли выудить переменную по названию, проще (и удобнее!) завести объект для хранения счетчиков
} else {
    counters[type]--;
}
var key = type+'Count';
io.sockets.emit('counter_'+usersOnline[socket.id], JSON.stringify({key: counters[type]}));
```

Comment: А есть вообще в node.js понятие класса? чтобы применить полиморфизм

Comment: @IOleg, есть, но не в node.js, а просто в js.

Comment: С комментариями в коде будьте полегче - это оскорбление

Comment: @IOleg, поверьте, когда я назвал себя тупым, мои чувства задеты не были.

Comment: if (increment) {
     counters[type]++;
     console.log(counters[type]); //выдает NaN 
 }

Comment: Проапдейтил. Я не знаю, какой там внешний код, поэтому не писал инициализацию (и var counters скорее всего должен оказаться на пару уровней вложенности выше, чем он есть здесь). **В increment должна оказаться переменная булева типа, либо надо заменить на старые if (increment === 'plus') и else if (increment === 'minus'), однако строчный подход нежелателен**.

Comment: я вас не понял... JSON.stringify({key: counters[type]})); - это у клиента приходит как объект вида {key: 1}

Comment: JSON.stringify({key: counters[type]})); нельзя так, key будет строкой key

Comment: @eicto да, прошляпился

Answer (score -4):

```
if (type == 'private') {
    if (increment == 'plus') {
        privateCount++;
    }else if(increment == 'minus') {
        privateCount--;
    }io.sockets.emit('counter_'+usersOnline[
        socket.id
    ],
    JSON.stringify({
        'privateCount' : privateCount
    }));
}else if (type == 'public') {
    if (increment == 'plus') {
        publicCount++;
    }else if(increment == 'minus') {
        publicCount--;
    }io.sockets.emit('counter_'+usersOnline[
        socket.id
    ],
    JSON.stringify({
        'publicCount' : publicCount
    }));
}else if (type == 'chat'){
    if (increment == 'plus') {
        chatCount++;
    }else if(increment == 'minus') {
        publicCount--;
    }io.sockets.emit('counter_'+usersOnline[
        socket.id
    ],
    JSON.stringify({
        'chatCount' : chatCount
    }));
}
}

http://tools.arantius.com/tabifier  этот сервис тебе помощь))
```

Comment: Вы хотя бы всматривались в свой листинг?

    io.sockets.emit('counter_'+usersOnline[
      socket.id
    ],

Это нормально?

Comment: А что здесь не так?

Comment: @IOleg, это не вам, это для @sevakjan